# How In a python list select the positive numbers values and multiply otherwise return the same value without modified the order on the list?

Tags: python

In a given list in python
`a = [1,-1,2,-2,3]`

I am looking to write a loop or code that multiply the positives ones by 2
for example, `i * 2 for i > 0  and i = i if i <= 0`  but returning the list in the original order like,
`b = [2,-1,4,-2,6]`

I tried different options and I tried to find some solution as well but unfortunately, I didn't.
I will be very glad if somebody could help

Comment: Probably relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: `[i*2 if i > 0 else i for i in a]`

Comment: Thank you The Lazy Scripter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop, and then replace as shown below.

```
a = [1,-1,2,-2,3]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] > 0:
        a[i] = a[i]*2`
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
a = [1, -1, 2, -2, 3]
b = [num * 2 if num > 0 else num for num in a]
```

This code is equivalent to writing:

```
a = [1, -1, 2, -2, 3]
b = []
for num in a:
    num *= 2 if num > 0 else 1
    b.append(num)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
a = [1, -1, 2, -2, 3]
b = []
for num in a:
    if num > 0:
        num *= 2
    b.append(num)
```